# cordova camera plugin issue with FILE_URI

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am using IONIC 3.7.0 in my current project. In one requirement I need to use cordova camera plugin to take photo uri from image gallery. Every time when I am trying to get the URI , I get the data_uri which is base64 long string.

I only need the file_uri of image to go further. Please suggest.

```
var options = {
              sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
              destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
          };
          Camera.getPicture(options)
              .then((imageData) => {
                  console.log(imageData);
                  this.fileToUpload = imageData;
                  const base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                  this.preloadImage._img.src = base64Image;
                  this.codeservice.doProfileImageUpload(base64Image)
                      .subscribe(res => {
                          if(res.length()>0){
                              console.log('updated');
                          }
                      })
          }, (err) => {
              console.log(err);
          });
```